# How can I say “¹⁄ₓ” in words?

Tags: numbers, mathematics

It is possible to state a fraction such as ¾ in words as follows:
*three fourths*.

Can someone please let me know how to say ¹⁄*ₓ* in words?

Comment: The reciprocal of x. One part in x.

Comment: To add on @kris's answer: one over x, or one divided by x.

Comment: Thank you all. So I cannot say one x-th. Right?

Comment: One over x is one of the most frequently used, especially in Calculus class. Edit: No you can't say one x-th. I have never heard anyone say this.

Comment: "An **nth**" is already well in use. So, it depends on the context: "In fact, the black holes took so much with **an xth** of a millisecond that they instantly reverted and became white holes." "... gas at position x. Leaving an **xth** of a tank so it can get back ...".

Comment: What would be the advantage in using this format?

Comment: do you actually want to say 1 xth (which I don't think you can say) or are you using x here to say 1 over anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of options, and none are particularly preferred because the need to phrase this specific quantity in everyday English is not common.

So, in no particular order:

- *One out of `x`*
- *One over `x`*
- *One `x`-th*

Choose whichever suits your needs or will work best for your audience.

Comment: Mathematician here! "One over x" is far and away the most common of those choices.

Comment: As a mathematician, would anyone in real life say “the reciprocal of x” for `1/x`? I didn’t put it in because the notation makes this feels like an elementary or arithmetic context,  as opposed to a more advanced or algebraic context, where I’d expect words like “reciprocal” to be paired with notations like `x^-1`. Not sure if I should add it as a suggestion to the answer or not.

Comment: It does depend on context. For example, if I were explaining how to solve the equation xy = 5 for the variable y (in terms of  the other variable x), I might say, "Multiply both sides by the reciprocal of x."